# Eigenvalues of a transpose multiplication

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say I have a matrix $\mathbf B \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$. Is it correct to say that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf B^T\cdot\mathbf B$ are always positive?

Comment: what happens if $B$ is a zero matrix?

Answer (score 3):

They are always non-negative.

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B^TB$ corresponding to an unit eigenvector $v$, then
$\langle v, B^T B v \rangle = \lambda = \langle Bv, B v \rangle = \|Bv\|^2$. Hence $\lambda \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ an eigenvector of $B^TB$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, which is real since $B^TB$ is symmetric, then

$$\lambda ||x||^2=\langle B^TB x,x\rangle=\langle Bx,Bx\rangle=||Bx||^2\implies \lambda\ge0$$